# division equivalent to peasant multiplication algorithm

Tags: algorithm, division

I'm looking for division algorithm which will be equivalent to peasant multiplication algorithm, but i coudlnt find anything  except fourier division algorithm, but maybe Someone coudl tell me about some other alogorithm ? Which will only use `+`,`-`and shifting operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do ordinary long division and write the numbers in base two you only need to do addition and subtraction because you work out the result one digit at a time. When microprocessors didn't have multiplication or division instructions this sort of thing was fairly common - see e.g. http://6502org.wikidot.com/software-math-intdiv

Comment: I dont know assembler at all coudl u explain code from site alittle?

Comment: There is a pseudo-code example and explanation at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm#Integer_division_.28unsigned.29_with_remainder